# Selecting multiple files and loop through all to perform actions based on names

Tags: excel, vba, loops, getopenfilename

I have wrote a code which has browse dialog to select multiple files and save file names in array and loop them one by one perform action based on keyword in filename.

1. as it has multi select option, I want to perform specific action based on    keyword in filename
2. am stuck in looping file names in array. I dkw where am going wrong
3. correct my syntax if I wrong, bear with me as am very new 
   to VBA
4. appreciate any help

   ```
   fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.CSV), *.CSV", Title:="Select File To Be Opened", MultiSelect:=True)
   If Not IsArray(fNameAndPath) Then Exit Sub

   For Each MyFile In fNameAndPath
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)==========(how to search for specific file name in myfile array.. 

       ' do stuff with workbook that has been opened

       if myfile= "*test_one*" then
           Set Fnd1 = Range("A1")
           Qty1 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(1), "*shop3**high*")
           For Cnt1 = 1 To Qty1
               Set Fnd1 = Rows(1).Find("*shop3**high*",Fnd1, , xlWhole, , , False, , False)
               max_num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Fnd1.EntireColumn)    ' maxnum value is copied to a cell in submit button
           Next Cnt1
       elseif myfile="*test_last*" then
           'similar to macro1
       elseif myfile=test3.csv then
           similar to macro1
       end if.
   wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
   Next MyFile
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Please clarify 'stuck in looping'. Do you mean you are stuck with an error, stuck inside the loop? If its an error please describe the exact error. Either way its always helpful to use the Debug option to Step through the code.

Comment: thanks for reply. am not stuck in loop or with any errors. its not working as expected. it just opens up first file and does nothing. 
How it should have worked: opens dialog box to browse for multiple files and run code according to keyword of filename. 
How it is: just opens first file if am selecting 3 files for an example and does nothing. Hope this clears up my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if myfile= "*test_one*" then
```

If you're looking for part of a filename then you want something like this:

```
If LCase(myfile) Like "*test_one*" Then
```

Comment: Hi thanks on correction. Yes am looking for keyword in a filename which is present in array of filenames. and then perform required action based on keyword of that file.